# Issue with def function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create Exponential Moving average. However, the error code 'Series' object is not callable' appeared. This is my code. Can someone help?

```
def CalculateEMA(window):

    sma = Close.rolling(window, min_periods=window).mean()[:window]
    rest = Close[window:]
    EMA_window=pd.concat([sma, rest]).ewm(span=window, adjust=False).mean()

    return EMA_window()
CalculateEMA(60)
```

Comment: `return EMA_window()`, you are trying to call a pandas `Series` object, it doesn't support that. Should it just be `return EMA_window`?

Comment: I wan to return an array, btw i remove the '()' and it works!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) that is returned from the `mean` method. 
This doesnt make any sense and since `Series` doesn't implement `__call__` it fails with an error.

What you probably want to do is remove the parens and just return the `Series` itself.

```
def CalculateEMA(window):

    sma = Close.rolling(window, min_periods=window).mean()[:window]
    rest = Close[window:]
    EMA_window=pd.concat([sma, rest]).ewm(span=window, adjust=False).mean()

    return EMA_window # <-- changed here
CalculateEMA(60)
```